# Matrix equation $(Ax - y)^T \cdot A = 0_n^T$ solve for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix equation

$$(A x - y)^T \cdot A = 0_n^T$$

Whereby $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$. A is not invertible, but $A^TA$ is invertible and the task is to solve for $x$.

$0_n$ is a $n$-dim vector of 0s, $(0,0,\dots,0)^T$ and $^T$ is the transpose of a matrix.

In order to solve it I transformed the equations in the following way:

\begin{align*}
(Ax - y)^T \cdot A &= 0_n^T\\
(x^TA^T-y^T) \cdot A &= 0_n^T\\
x^TA^T \cdot A - y^T A &= 0_n^T\\
x^TA^T \cdot A &= y^T A\\
x^T &= (y^T \cdot A) \cdot (A^TA)^{-1}\\
x   &= ((y^T \cdot A) \cdot (A^TA)^{-1})^T\\
x   &= A^T \cdot y \cdot ((A^TA)^{-1})^T
\end{align*}

Is this legal or have I missed something?

Comment: what do you mean by $A^{T}$ ?

Comment: Isn't this the hard way? What's wrong with $Ax-y=0,Ax=y,A^tAx=A^ty,x=(A^tA)^{-1}A^ty$?

Comment: @Matrix, presumably the transpose.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry I forgot the additional $\cdot A$ on the left side of the equation

Comment: if $A^{T}$ is the transpose, so i think that equation is equivalent to $Ax - y= 0_n$, because ${(A^T)}^{T}=A$.

Comment: In that case, the 1st line of your solution also needs editing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sorry for my sloppiness

Comment: Also, I think you meant to say that $A^tA$ is invertible, but you stopped short.

Comment: Also, why aren't you simplifying $0+z$ to $z$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I forgot about that, I changed it, too.

Comment: Isn't $y^T=y$ due to the fact $y$ is a scalar? (I'm not correcting per se.) Similarly for $x^T$? I think I may misunderstand the notation employed in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @Limitless I don't think so, $y$ is a vector, not a scalar, otherwise I would agree

Comment: @Mahoni, oh wow! Stupid moment there! I had forgot the LARGE difference between vectors and scalars... My apologies and personal embarrassment. :p

Comment: $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ so the last line is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to the sixth line of displayed equations, you are fine, thus $x=(y^TAB^{-1})^T$ with $B=A^TA$ (and $B$ is assumed to be invertible hence $B^{-1}$ exists), that is, $x=(B^{-1})^TA^Ty$ (do not forget that $(MN)^T=N^TM^T$, if only for dimension reasons).

Now, $(B^{-1})^T=(B^T)^{-1}$ (this always holds) and $B^T=(A^TA)^T=A^T(A^T)^T=A^TA=B$ hence 
$$
x=B^{-1}A^Ty,\qquad B=A^TA.
$$
**Dimensional analysis:** The matrix $A$ has dimension $d\times n$ hence $A^T$ has dimension $n\times d$ and $B=A^TA$ has dimension $n\times$ <s>*d*</s> $\times$ <s>*d*</s> $ \times n=n\times n$, as well as $B^{-1}$. As a column vector, $y$ has dimension $d\times1$ hence $B^{-1}A^Ty$ has dimension $n\times$ <s>*n*</s> $\times$ <s>*n*</s> $\times$ <s>*d*</s> $\times$ <s>*d*</s> $\times 1=n\times 1$. All is well.